# Auto text formatting on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm working on a syntax and lexical analyzer for our compiler class. The `JTextArea` for the input code, I would like to add a language styler into it. It would work by automatically changing the color of the text if it equals to a certain word.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Take a look at http://bobbylight.github.io/RSyntaxTextArea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) does not support styled text. [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) does.

The official tutorial should be a good start: [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)